# How to tell Maven to include the jar dependency, not the subproject source directory in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I use Apache Maven to manage my Java libs (jar) and some of projects that use the libs. For convinience, I use `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to generate *Eclipse project files* which can be imported into Eclipse workspace for editing.

Problems arise when I edit the main project and Java lib projects in the same Eclipse workspace. That is, `mvn eclipse:eclipse` includes **src path** dependency in `.classpath` file, not the `jar` dependency as expected.

Say I have a Jave lib project named `mylib`. The corresponding jar file `mylib.jar` has been deployed to a private Maven repo maintained by me. In order to use mylib.jar in the main project, the following dependency is included in `pom.xml`.

```
<!-- pom.xml for the main project -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>namespace.my</groupId>
  <artifactId>mylib</artifactId>
  <version>[1.0, )</version>
</dependency>
```

`mvn compile` and `mvn test` work perfect, in which `mylib.jar` is automatically downloaded from my repo. However, when trying `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, I find the generated `.classpath` file doesn't include `mylib.jar` dependency as expected. Instead, it includes source file directory for mylib as follows.

```
<!-- .classpath file generated by mvn eclipse:eclipse -->
<classpathentry kind="src" path="/mylib"/>
```

It seems that Maven reads Eclipse's metadata and finds mylib and the main project coexits in the same workspace. Therefore maven includes the source for my good. Damn. How can I tell maven to ignore the local project source and just include the jar file?

Comment: Why don't you use the m2e Eclipse plugin instead?

Comment: Because I feel comfortable to type commands in console -- compilation, test, packaging are all done in one command. Besides, useful configuration segments in pom.xml can be easily reused in other projects. Eclipse is good, but too many menus plus numerous plugins look complicated for me.

Comment: The two aren't necessarily mutually exclusive, even though you'd have to give up on the Maven Eclipse plugin in order to use m2e. I find Eclipse convenient for debugging and m2e guarantees that the build process is as similar as possible inside and outside Eclipse.

Comment: They _are_ mutually exclusive - you can't use both together. m2e is really great (as is [m2e-wtp](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/)), but can be a real pain when you have plugins configured that it can't handle and it pollutes your pom with "lifecycle mappings". The maven eclipse plugin is quick and simple but gets the job done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe this is actually because they're related projects in Eclipse. So if you right-click on your main project and go to `Project References` your lib project should be ticked.

If you run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` it will automatically add project references for any sub-projects (modules).  You can change this with the [useProjectReferences](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html#useProjectReferences) property of the maven eclipse plugin.

It defaults to `true`, but

> When set to false, the plugin will not create sub-projects and instead
>   reference those sub-projects using the installed package in the local
>   repository

To use the property either set the property in your pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <useProjectReferences>false</useProjectReferences>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    <plugins>
<build>
```

Or as a property on the command line:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Declipse.useProjectReferences=false
```

Answer (score 11):

I need to avoid to include the dependency as a refrenced project, but as a jar.
Using Eclipse 4.6 Neon none of the previous solutions work.

I had disable the `Workspace Resolution` feature

```
click on the project -> Maven -> Disable Workspace Resolution
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Hound Dog's hints. Yes, [useProjectReferences](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html#useProjectReferences) controls Maven how to handle sub projects -- including source dir or including jar files.

I haven't installed the maven plugin for Eclipse, so I add the following configuration in `pom.xml`. It tells Maven to include jar dependency in local maven repo, not the source dir. If the required jar file is not present in local repo, it will be automatically downloaded on the fly.

```
  <!-- pom.xml for the main project: include jar, not src path -->
  <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
            <useProjectReferences>false</useProjectReferences>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Now `mvn eclipse:eclipse` works as expected.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect this, as well as the command line alternative. If you're happy with that, don't forget to select it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Just try using the type element inside dependency tag and mention source/jar as the type in your pom.xml

```
<!-- pom.xml for the main project --> 
<dependency>
   <groupId>namespace.my</groupId>
   <artifactId>mylib</artifactId>
   <version>[1.0, )</version>
   <type>jar<type> <!-- source/jar -->
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently experienced that this behaviour is triggered by the version stated in the pom.xml files. If the version of the lib your primary project is depending on is available to eclipse in the workspace (e.g. a project with the matching pom.xml [group,artifact,version] for the lib) this will be used as a project reference in stead of being pulled from the M2REPO-location.

My solution was to change the version of the library pom.xml in the workspace to another version allowing me to improve the lib, while the primary project still pulled the older lib from M2REPO.

Using this by aligning the version numbers allows you to perform concurrent artifact improvements/alterations with little hassle.

I have not yet tested if you need to run the `mvn eclipse:eclipse` every time you change the lib pom.xml files and the primary pom.xml dependencies, but I would expect it to be so.

Answer (score 0):

I tried closing the project in eclipse & the workspace just built itself, this time taking the jar from the repository instead of linking the project