# Maven dependency project export

Tags: spring, maven, m2eclipse

I am using Spring in two 2 projects. First, I have a "web" project which depends on my second project that is a normal java project with maven nature enabled that I named "core".
So, in my "web" project I just add the reference of my "core" project:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

If I set the property "useProjectReferences" to false like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12577346/852841), everything works fine, But I am in developing phase, I don't wanna run maven install everytime I have a change in my "core" project.
I am running my projects in tomcat, so I can't package them in ear. All that I want is Maven export my "src/main/resources" source folder to Spring be able to find my `coreContext.xml` and bind my beans. What I have tried in my "core" `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}src/main/resources</directory>
            <targetPath>${basedir}WEB-INF/resources</targetPath>
        </resource>
             ...
```

I tried to use shade-plugin but without success too. Any tip would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to create a [Multi Module Maven Project](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-intro.html) which contains both the core and web projects.

Comment: Thanks, that way maven always generate the jar for me. It solved my problem.